# replay failed to start see vugen log for more details - error when replayed vugen

Tags: vugen, replay, truclient

I am using Loadrunner 2020 community edition. I have created a script in TruClient and when trying to replay in develop script mode, getting 'replay failed to start see vugen log for more details' error.
'logfile.log' was empty and 'mdrv.log' file had last replay log details when checked. Are those the files vugen referring to? What is the solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue, but was able to fix it as follows.

When I compiled the script, I did not see any errors in the output, so I checked the "Output -> Chromium(IE) - Interactive Replay" log which had several errors related to parameter files. When I fixed those, I was able to replay the script.

Output Log Path
[image: Output Log Path]